# Typescript map like data structure for efficient retrieve

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, declarative

What would be an efficient way to define a data structure that would cater for the bellow example?

MealType and Topping are unlikely to be changed, but might change in the future.

Looking for a declarative, functional way to build this data structure and have a retrieve in a `map.retrieve(selectedMealType, selectedToppingMix)`-flavour.

```js
// can only be one type of meal selected
export enum MealType {
  Salad,
  Pizza,
  Pastry
}

// can be none, one, or many (any combination of) toppings selected
export enum Topping {
  Cheese,
  Ham,
  Tomatoes
}

// expected output

// All possible combinations of
// Salad
//      : with no toppings
//      : with Cheese                   --> and assign specific string/value for it
//      : with Cheese, Ham              --> and assign specific string/value for it
//      : with Cheese, Tomatoes         --> and assign specific string/value for it
//      : with Cheese, Ham, Tomatoes    --> and assign specific string/value for it
//      : with Ham                      --> and assign specific string/value for it
//      : with Ham, Tomatoes            --> and assign specific string/value for it
//      : with Ham, Tomatoes            --> and assign specific string/value for it

// ... same for Pizza and Pastry
```

Having it static would be ok.

How would you build it and then access the values?

Comment: I doubt it really needs to be super-efficient given your very limited key space. But for efficient retrieval, consider the [builtin `Map` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) - keyed by a string containing meal and a sorted list of toppings. That said, how "functional" do you want it, do you require immutability? Real *set*s of toppings as keys?

Comment: The above is just an abstraction, but you're right, the key-space is not large. There are 5 'meal types' and 7 'topics'. It's funny, as what am working on has nothing to do with food, but I thought this makes it easier to grasp rather than some obscure domain-specific knowledge/terms. Immutability would be ideal.

Comment: With 7 "toppings" you might want to represent them as a bit field, e.g., where each enum is a power of 2 and a set is uniquely represented by their sum.

Comment: Ah, ok, 5*2^7 is medium-sized, no longer small. If you want an immutable implementation, best choose one of the many libraries that offer immutable datastructures - don't implement this yourself.

Comment: But notice that of the questions "*How to do this with the standard-library?*", "*How to do this quick, small and dirty?*", "*Which library to choose?*" and "*How to implement my own data structure for this?*" only the first two are on-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you have a way to do this "quick, small and dirty"?

Comment: I don't understand the "expected output", really... how do you *want* to do the initialization?

Comment: @flashjpr A frozen object literal using meal type and jcalz' bitfield as a key, with a helper function that transforms `selectedMealType, selectedToppingMix` into the lookup format.

Comment: Or [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAslDeUDKAaKAFAXm9BDKAvlKJFACoJQDCaAEmhQQLABQAliAC7ABOAZrgDGwWBUQQAXLDScpZANoBdQqz5gQgzmwD2IKBFwBrYDFwAHADxkAfAAoAdI+BTbMCgDJKANzmEAlEp+CKxQoVCCugDOnFCc2gDSwACeUAC8ULYQsqJBqdb6nPbQANRQAEQSZVClWfaFkQA2bMK2fvaR2jycrfYAVtoctmUA3GV+wyFhESDRUGxSiPKGUtE8HADmir4APlDqACbAfBzA+4RpCAQTLGHE9nydAKJCABa2Inlz8nGJSe9+ynSwHsXnGk1CPGAnDAPD0iEhnDWwC8zgyWSkbly+TY3wSyUynABKhYzBYDSh+nMFwMxlMZlsk3EGPsqFiUiUaB85Ua+yqBBQjP0zKwMnZZHsVEUnKkZTMmEwUAA7uEXpE+QKbpRJLB7HhRVB5OL6OR7GQpVAubLcJElVAXrhoJ5BKq+aw-KxyTEbekDGZ7AikSjbEydXq2QbxWQGPZaMoCH4gA) maybe? ‍♂️